# C# 'Task' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Threading'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Task;`

`namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am just trying to get started off in C#, and as I was writing my helloworld, I met my first compilation error.

> ERROR: Script compilation failed. [CompilationErrorException] error
>   CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Task' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Threading' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I am running the latest .NET editing in VScode.
Hope for your help.

Comment: Do you have the required references added into your project? Also, why even have any of those using statements for a helloworld app?

Comment: What framework version are you targeting?

Comment: @TJWolschon - Those are included by default (at least for .NET 4.7 console apps).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you looking for the Task in System.Threading.Tasks?

Note the 's' at the end.

Full reference is System.Threading.Tasks.Task, or for a using, System.Threading.Task**s**.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `using System.Threading.Task;`, you're not using Tasks at this point, and if you're just starting in C#, you probably won't for a while.

Also, it appears you have an errant character before the word `namespace`.